# Display row with maximum value in each group by in Mysql

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have a 'field_revision...' table that I am trying to grab information from. With my current query it is returning all entity_id's that match the value even if the revision_id is less than the HIGHEST one for that specific id. Below is an example table:

```
entity_id   revision_id     enable_value
      781          2313                0
      781          2314                1
      783          2316                1
      783          2318                0
      784          2317                0
      786          2321                1
      786          2322                1
```

I need a query that will return all entity_ids where enable_value = true AND the revision_id is the highest. For this sample table the query needs to return 781 and 786 since both of these are true for the highest revision id.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM
  field_revision T1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT entity_id,MAX(revision_id) AS revision_id
  FROM
  field_revision
  GROUP BY entity_id) T2 ON T1.entity_id = T2.entity_id AND T1.revision_id = T2.revision_id
    WHERE T1.enable_value=1
```

**EDIT**: Explanation for OP

T1 - Alias for `field_revision`

T2 - View of `field_revision` with `entity_id` wise and with maximun of `revision_id`.

So  while INNER JOINING We connect T2 WITH T1 using `entity_id` and max(`revision_id`), and print corresponding entries in T1

Hope this helps..

Comment: It worked but I have no idea why. We are selecting all from the table, yes, we then make an alias for the table 't1' and we are inner joining the same table but it will only contain the result of the 2nd select query (ending with the Group by entity_id)? So the ending part we are just matching everything and then adding our where clause, right. What does SELECT entity_id,MAX(revision_id) AS revision_id mean. Can you just add a short explanation to your answer? Thanks

Comment: Should i give explanation in answer?

Comment: I won't accept this answer. If ANYONE without a good understanding of mysql came across this exact issue they will not understand, even after your 'edit', why this query would work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the `entity_id` then you can try this (but i think @Subin C Poonamgode's answer is the correct one):

```
SELECT DISTINCT aa.entity_id
FROM field_revision AS aa
INNER JOIN field_revision AS bb
ON aa.entity_id = bb.entity_id
WHERE aa.revision_id > bb.revision_id AND aa.enable_value = 1;
```